# Webmin shows plain Perl script when try to open login page

Tags: ubuntu, login, perl, cgi, webmin

when I try to open webmin login page "https://192.168.1.13:10000" it shows plain Perl script like below, what is problem?
I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and latest version of webmin.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#
# Authentic Theme (https://github.com/authentic-theme/authentic-theme)
# Copyright Ilia Rostovtsev 
# Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/authentic-theme/authentic-theme/blob/master/LICENSE)
#
use strict;

use File::Basename;

our (%in, %gconfig, %tconfig, %text, $config_directory, $current_theme, %theme_text);

do(dirname(__FILE__) . "/authentic-lib.pl");

my %miniserv;
get_miniserv_config(\%miniserv);

my $charset = &get_charset();

# Check to add error handler
error_40x_handler();

our %theme_config = (settings($config_directory . "/$current_theme/settings-admin", 'settings_'),
                     settings($config_directory . "/$current_theme/settings-root",  'settings_'));

# Show pre-login text banner
if ($gconfig{'loginbanner'} &&
    get_env('http_cookie') !~ /banner=1/ &&
    !$in{'logout'}                       &&
    !$in{'failed'}                       &&
    !$in{'timed_out'})
{

    print "Auth-type: auth-required=1\r\n";
    print "Set-Cookie: banner=1; path=/\r\n";
    &PrintHeader($charset);
    print '', "\n";
    print '', "\n";
    embed_login_head();
    print '' . "\n";
    embed_overlay_prebody();
    print
'

'
      . "\n";
    my $url = $in{'page'};
    open(BANNER, $gconfig{'loginbanner'});

    while () {
        s/LOGINURL/$url/g;
        print;
    }

    close(BANNER);
    &footer();
    return;
}

my $sec = lc(get_env('https')) eq 'on' ? "; secure" : "";
my $sidname = $miniserv{'sidname'} || "sid";
print "Auth-type: auth-required=1\r\n";
print "Set-Cookie: banner=0; path=/$sec\r\n"   if ($gconfig{'loginbanner'});
print "Set-Cookie: $sidname=x; path=/$sec\r\n" if ($in{'logout'});
print "Set-Cookie: redirect=1; path=/\r\n";
print "Set-Cookie: testing=1; path=/$sec\r\n";
&PrintHeader($charset);
print '', "\n";
print '', "\n";
embed_login_head();
print '' . "\n";
embed_overlay_prebody();
print '' . "\n";

if (defined($in{'failed'})) {
    if ($in{'twofactor_msg'}) {
        print "",, "\n";
        print '' . "\n";
        print ' ' . $theme_text{'login_warning'} .
          '
' . &theme_text('session_twofailed', &html_escape($in{'twofactor_msg'})) . "\n";
        print '' . "\n";
    } else {
        print '' . "\n";
        print ' ' .
          $theme_text{'login_warning'} . '
' . "\n";
        print '' . $theme_text{'theme_xhred_session_failed'} . "\n";
        print '' . "\n";
    }
} elsif ($in{'logout'}) {
    print '' . "\n";
    print ' ' . $theme_text{'login_success'} . '
' . "\n";
    print '' . $theme_text{'session_logout'} . "\n";
    print '' . "\n";
} elsif ($in{'timed_out'}) {
    print '' . "\n";
    print ' ' .
      $theme_text{'login_warning'} . '
' . "\n";
    print '' . &theme_text('session_timed_out', int($in{'timed_out'} / 60)) . "\n";
    print '' . "\n";
}
print "$text{'session_prefix'}\n";
print '' . "\n";

print '
     '
  . (&get_product_name() eq 'webmin' ? $theme_text{'theme_xhred_titles_wm'} :
       $theme_text{'theme_xhred_titles_um'}
  ) .
  '' . "\n";

# Process logo
embed_logo();

# Login message
my $host;
if ($gconfig{'realname'}) {
    $host = &get_display_hostname();
} else {
    $host = get_env('server_name');
    $host =~ s/:\d+//g;
    $host = &html_escape($host);
}
print '' . &theme_text('login_message') . ' ' . $host . '' . "\n";
print '' . "\n";
print '' . "\n";
print
'' . "\n";
print '' . "\n";
print '' . "\n";
print '' . "\n";
print
  '' . "\n";
print '' . "\n";

if ($miniserv{'twofactor_provider'}) {
    print '' . "\n";
    print '' . "\n";
    print
'' . "\n";
    print '' . "\n";
}
if (!$gconfig{'noremember'}) {
    print '
             '
      . $theme_text{'login_save'} . '
         ' . "\n";
}
print '';
print '  ' .
  &theme_text('login_signin') . '' . "\n";

if ($text{'session_postfix'} =~ "href") {
    my $link = get_link($text{'session_postfix'}, 'ugly');

    print '[0] . '", "' . $link->[1] .
'", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,width=700,height=500");return false;\' class="btn btn-warning">  '
      . &theme_text('login_reset')
      . '' . "\n";
}

print '';
print '' . "\n";

&footer();
```

Comment: Is the webmin service running? Is this a new install or have you had it running previously? Webmin have their own forum http://www.webmin.com/community.html where you might get an answer.

Comment: Yes webmin is running. It's not new installation. I had it running previously. Don't know why this happened

Comment: Webmin is pretty reliable and I'm out of ideas already. Best thing to do would be ask the developers, I believe they are good at following up issues. Check that miniserv.conf in /etc/webmin isn't corrupted and that firewall rules haven't change. Port 10000 must be open and accessible.

Comment: I change port and open it in firewall but problem still exist.miniserv.conf hasn't changed.

Comment: usermin login page https://192.168.1.13:20000 works fine but webmin login page doesn't

Comment: I'm out of ideas. I use webmin on one of my machines but I'm not an expert in it. As I mentioned in a previous comment perhaps you should ask your question on their forum. They seem to support webmin pretty well.

Comment: I asked on webmin forum but no answer yet

Comment: What happens if you try to load webmin on the machine with webmin on it. What I mean is, if webmin is on a remote machine not, if you ssh into it and load it locally? If there is no desktop on the remote, install links (sudo apt install links or sudo yum install links etc). It wont give you a graphical representation but it will tell you if the issue is from outside or inside.

Comment: Also, the script shown is /usr/libexec/webmin/session_login.cgi and it is work checking the permissions and ownership. I'm plucking at straws here but check they are owned by root and -rwxr-xr-x

Comment: I used links to load https://192.168.1.13:10000/ locally as you said  and get the same result. also I check the permissions and ownership for /usr/share/webmin/authentic-theme/session_login.cgi and it is owned by root and -rwxr-xr-x . (/usr/libexec/webmin/session_login.cgi for this location I get no such file or directory )

Comment: and also for /usr/share/webmin/session_login.cgi owned by root and -rwxr-xr-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
in /etc/webmin/miniserv.conf file line "addtype_cgi=internal/cgi" was "ddtype_cgi=internal/cgi" first 'a' character was deleted. my silly mistake :|

@Admiral Noisy Bottom, thank you very much for your help.